# Sending ACK greatly slows down data transfer

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

Awareness of the fact that TCP checksum is actually a very poor checksum prompted me to include in the data block an additional checksum (SHA-256) to verify the integrity of data on the server and in case of corrupted, request the data block again. But the addition of ACK greatly reduces the data transfer rate. In my case (the data is transmitted by wifi) the speed has decreased from ~90mbps to ~12mbps.

Client:

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.31.30", 3333));
ByteBuffer byteBufferData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024 * 8);
ByteBuffer byteBufferACK = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    // write data (payload + checksum (SHA-256))
    socketChannel.write(byteBufferData);
    byteBufferData.clear();
    // read ACK
    socketChannel.read(byteBufferACK);
    byteBufferACK.clear();
    // if (byteBufferACK.get() == XXX)
        // ... retransmission byteBufferData
}
```

Server:

```
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(3333));
    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
    ByteBuffer byteBufferData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024 * 8);
    ByteBuffer byteBufferACK = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while ((socketChannel.read(byteBufferData)) != -1) {
        // when 8192 bytes of data were read
        if (!byteBufferData.hasRemaining()) {
            byteBufferData.clear();
            // write ACK
            socketChannel.write(byteBufferACK);
            byteBufferACK.clear();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

Please note that the code is a test code and is not intended to convey any useful data. It is intended only for testing the data transfer rate.

I have as 2 questions:

1. Maybe I do not understand something or do it incorrectly, but why sending one byte of data as a confirmation of data acceptance (ACK) affects the overall data transfer rate so much? How to avoid this?
2. Is the SHA-256 sufficient as a checksum for data of 8kb size? (On top of the existing TCP CRC)

Comment: The TCP checksum is an excellent checksum that's stood the test of time. What are your requirements that you think you need SHA-256? Cryptographic checksums are designed to foil sophisticated attacks. Against typical communication channel errors they perform no better than much more efficient checksums, and sometimes worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're waiting for it.  Lets say there's 200ms of latency between you and the server.  Without the ack, you'd write packets as quickly as possible, saturate the bandwidth, and stop.  With the ack, it looks like this:

```
t=0  send 1st 8k
t=200 server recieves
t=205ish  server sends ack
t=405 client recieves ack.
t=410ish client sends 2nd 8k
```

You waste 50% of your sending time.  I'm actually surprised it wasn't worse.

TCP has a LOT of features in it that prevent these kinds of issues, including sliding windows of data (you don't send one packet and ack it, you send N packets and the server acks the ones it receives, allowing missing packets to be resent out of order).  YOu're reimplementing TCP badly and almost certainly shouldn't be.

If you are going to do this-  don't use TCP.  Use UDP or raw sockets and write your new protocol on top of that.  You're still using TCP acks and checksums, so yours are redundant.